# spark read json string in query

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have table inspark, one column named ("mappings") have key-value pair as string
select mappings from hello;
Ex: {"foo": "baar", "foo1": "bar1" }

I want to cast "mappings" column into a MAP and read value of foo1
like select CAST("mappings" as MAP) from hello;
This will throw error in spark sql. How can we translate this to map

Comment: Check out `from_json`

Comment: Can you please present an example of an input with its desired output?